# Bad render quality

Tags: rendering

I have one animation project where i use Cycles Render. After rendering i wasnt happy with results (Image 2) What is problem and what is solution?
(Samp - rend 256. prev 2; Using GPU; Tiles 256 256)

[image: This is how it looks in object mode]

[image: and this is how it looks after rendering]

HOW TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM - 
There are two ways how to solve it. First - MCprep addon, this addon is needed if you want import your minecraft world into blender with textures. If you import them you need click on prep material [link]
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyQaV.jpg - red line - in which software was obj. from save created and blue line is the solve.) OR you can click on material and change from linear to closest [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAhiO.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Please don't write 'solved' in the title. If an answer solves your question you can 'accept' it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough info to be sure, but I think your problem is that lighting does not match the "Minecraft" look. My suggestion is : change the material of your objects to emmision. 
There also seems to be some bluring of the textures which should be fixed if you render. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, problem was in MCprep i didnt Prep materials, so if you have same problem, go to MCprep, choose your world exporter and click on Prep Materials. But anyway, thanks Cos Dim :)

Comment: Can you clarify what is "MCprep" and "world exporter"? Some screenshots, description?

Comment: Hi @Mr Zak , there are two ways how to solve it. First - MCprep addon, this addon is needed if you want import your minecraft world into blender with textures. If you import them you need click on prep material [link]
 (https://imgur.com/u8Xh0MA - red line - in which software was obj. from save created and blue line is the solve.) OR you can click on material and change from linear to closest [link] (https://imgur.com/107pOVY)